# Удалить элемент массива

Tags: java

Как правильно вывести элементы массива на консоль с учетом удаленного элемента.

```
public class Remove {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {77, 99, 44, 55, 22, 88, 11 , 0, 66, 33, 10} ;
        int count = 0;
        int element = 0;
        int searchKey;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        searchKey = 77;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i] == searchKey){
                element = i;
                count++;
            }
        }

        for(int j = element; j < arr.length; j++){
            arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = {77, 99, 44, 55, 22, 88, 11, 0, 66, 33, 10};
        
        arr = removeValue(arr, 77);
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
    
    public static int[] removeValue(int[] array, int value)
    {
        int[] result = new int[array.length -1];
        int c = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if(array[i] != value)
            {
                result[c] = array[i];
                c++;
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

Вот вариант без листов, если Вам так будет удобнее.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала надо разобраться как корректно удалить элементы из массива, а вывести уже не проблема

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Remove {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {77, 99, 44, 55, 22, 88, 11, 0, 66, 33, 10};
        int removeValue=77;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        
        int[] result = removeByIndex(arr, removeValue);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
    
    public static int[] removeByIndex(int[] array, int value) {
        return Arrays.stream(array)
                .filter(i->i!=value)
                .toArray();
    }
    
}
```

Без стримов есть несколько вариантов, но это в любом случае менее рационально:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Remove {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {77, 99, 44, 55, 22, 88, 11, 0, 66, 33, 10};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        
        System.out.println(removeByIndex(arr, 99));
    }
    
    public static List <Integer> removeByIndex(int [] array, int value) {
        List <Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int element : array) {
            if (element!=value) list.add(element);
        }
        return list;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: как выводит без stream. Я пока не знаю как он работает

Comment: @Rasim Zamaltdinov ответ дополнил